# Error when trying to get document.getElementsByName(name)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to use this code in one of my projects:

https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib

EDIT: Link to code in question http://jsfiddle.net/BvFNf/3/

The code in its current form uses:

```
var byId = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
    base = difflib.stringAsLines(byId("baseText").value),
    newtxt = difflib.stringAsLines(byId("newText").value),
```

However I am trying to use the name field instead:

```
var byName = function (name) { return document.getElementsByName(name); }
    base = difflib.stringAsLines(byName("field1")[0].value),
    newtxt = difflib.stringAsLines(byName("field2")[0].value),
```

The append child code is as follows:

```
        diffoutputdiv.appendChild(diffview.buildView({
            baseTextLines: base,
            newTextLines: newtxt,
            //opcodes: opcodes,
            baseTextName: "Base Text",
            newTextName: "New Text",
            contextSize: contextSize,
            viewType: viewType
    }));
```

I also added `' name="field1" '` to the html.

The full source can be found here: [Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/7y3SQYFM)
The error I keep getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild' demo.html:69
diffUsingJS demo.html:69
onclick demo.html:98
```

The data being returned is equivalent to the original byID data set. Please help.

Comment: There's no `appendChild` in your posted code. But looking at the pastebin code, the problem is rather noticeable. You forgot to get the element when using `byName`, that is `diffoutputdiv = byName("diffoutput")[0]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Somehow you're getting multiple elements in `diffoutputdiv`...the code expects it to be a single `<div>`, not a NodeList which is apparently what it's been assigned to.

Comment: Ah, I know why - it's because you changed `getElementById` to `getElementByName`...I'll see if I can come up with an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
//diffoutputdiv = byId("diffoutput"),
diffoutputdiv = byName("diffoutput"),
```

In your transition from `byId` to `byName` you forgot to get the element from the returned list of matches. Again, `getElementsByName` return a list of nodes, and `getElementById` returns a single node.

```
diffoutputdiv = byName("diffoutput")[0]
```